# Data not displaying inside the while loop

Tags: javascript, php

When I directly access the php file the data will display but when passing back the data into ajax the data inside the loop will not display.

showpercenage.php

```
<?php
$get_id = $_POST;
$landing_id = implode(" ",$get_id);

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT
              percentage.percent_id,
              percentage.landing_id,
              percentage.percentage,
              percentage.date_recorded
              FROM
              percentage
              WHERE percentage.landing_id = '$landing_id'");`
$number = 1;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $data .= '
      <tr>
        <td><center>' . $number . '</center></td>
        <td><center>' . $row['percent_id'] . '</center></td>
        <td><center>' . $row['landing_id'] . '</center></td>
        <td><center>' . $row['percentage'] . '%</center></td>
        <td><center>' . date("M. d, Y", strtotime($row['date_recorded'])) . '</center></td>
      </tr>';
    $number++;
  }

echo $data;
?>
```

js file

```
function readRecords() {
  $.get("ajax/showpercent.php", {}, function (data, status) {
    $(".display_percentage").html(data);
  });
}
```

Anyone can help me how to fix this.

Comment: What about is not showing? Are you getting the rows? If not, then you may not have any results to fetch.

Comment: @aynber when i directly access the php file the data will display but displaying it from ajax the data inside the loop will not display..

Comment: Please clarify your question with an [edit]. What do you mean "not displaying data inside the while loop"? Do you mean the loop is not being entered? Show your research with an [edit]. And show your results. If you are not entering the loop under some circumstances that is the real question and you should focus on that.

Comment: Open developers console, see the response form ajax request. __Make sure__ you have `.display_percentage` element on the page.

Comment: If the $_POST is not properly set, there's a possibility why the data inside the loop is not display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your $data variable before while loop.

```
$number = 1;
$data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        $data .= '
          <tr>
            <td><center>' . $number . '</center></td>
            <td><center>' . $row['percent_id'] . '</center></td>
            <td><center>' . $row['landing_id'] . '</center></td>
            <td><center>' . $row['percentage'] . '%</center></td>
            <td><center>' . date("M. d, Y", strtotime($row['date_recorded'])) . '</center></td>
          </tr>';
        $number++;
}

echo $data;
```

Comment: no error but the data inside the loop is not displaying.

Comment: Anyway data variable must be defined at first, then it can be concated, define it before loop and try to catch your fetch results

Comment: var_dump($row) in your while, may be it just does not loop